# What files should I package with my vagrant box?

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, vagrantfile

I've created a new box and I'm ready to [package](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/cli/package.html) it.  However, can someone help me understand which files I should package along with it?

The files I currently have for my vagrant config looks something like:

```
Vagrantfile
- ansible
     build-playbook.yml
     packages-playbook.yml
     vm-playbook.yml
     - templates
          Makefile
- tools
     apache-ant.tar.gz
     jython_installer.jar
```

I was planning on adding them all (via the `--include` flag to `vagrant package`) as they could get referenced by someone wanting to do a `vagrant provision` once they download my box.  Does that sound right?  And, on a related note, could I pass folders into the `--include` flag?

Answer (score 1):

> Does that sound right?

Yes, this is certainly something you can do and can help the provisioning.
With ansible though, I believe the user who will download the box would need to have ansible setup.

> And, on a related note, could I pass folders into the --include flag?

Yes you can - you can review  https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/344 as there trick when you reference the folder from the Vagrantfile packaged in your box, would need to be something like (for puppet but the idea of reference folder is there)

```
config.vm.provision :puppet, :module_path => File.expand_path("../modules", __FILE__)
```